# How do I hide the "Cloudcommons" field for a specific group in the Hybris Backoffice search tree

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, restriction, usergroups, backoffice, principal

I am using Hybris version 20.05(Cloud).
There is a "Cloudcommens" field in the backoffice tree.
But if there is "TestRabia" in the group of the logged in employee, I don't want the user to see the "Cloudcommens" field.
But the user who still has "TestRabia(UserGroup)" sees the "Cloudcommens" field.

For this :
...backoffice-backoffice-config.xml I add the following code:

```
<context merge-by="principal" component="explorer-tree" principal="TestRabia">
    <explorer-tree:explorer-tree xmlns:explorer-tree="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree">
        <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc.cloudcommons" merge-mode="remove" />
    </explorer-tree:explorer-tree>
</context>
```

**How can I solve this problem?**
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: I hope you have performed the Backoffice reset.

Comment: Yes, I did the reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the type of group I want to restrict is UserGroup, I could not do this restriction.
The principal context code I wrote works when I change my group's type to BackkoficeRole.